# Migrating from Java 6, Ant to Java 13, Maven

Tags: maven, ant, migration, java-6, java-13

We have a system which runs on Java 6 and uses Ant. I want to migrate the system to Java 13 and Maven.

1. What are the things that I need to consider when performing this migration? I understand that some third party libraries may cause issues but I'm hoping that all the Java libraries will work smoothly as before.
2. What is the easiest way to follow in doing this? Is there a plugin in an IDE which can perform the Ant to Maven migration easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you then I would separate the two upgrades. JDK 6 to JDK 13 may be easy or may be a big task. Similarly, moving from `ant` to Maven may be straight-forward or may be a big task. It might be easier to do one before the other. Assuming you have a recent version of `ant` then it should work okay on JDK 13.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice @AlanBateman !! Yes, it seems it will be easier to handle one migration at a time rather than mixing it both. I will use a newer ant version and build with JDK 13 first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First migration is a manual process

1. Change the directory to follow [Maven conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
2. Create one/more pom files which fill your needs. Do you have multiple modules?
3. Try to build with maven
4. Are you within a company? Yes start with a repository manager
5. Make configuration (settings.xml).
6. Start to build with JDK 8 first (expect issues with libraries)
7. Try to build with JDK 11 (expect some issue with libraries)
8. Finally JDK 13

Comment: Thank you very much for the ordered process @khmarbaise ! As there are multiple modules I will create pom files for each. Can you please tell me why you are suggesting to build with JDK 8 and JDK 11 first?